# Setting up LaTeX Compiler in PyCharm on Mac OS

Tags: miktex, mac, texify-idea

I am having trouble setting up a LaTeX project in my PyCharm on MacOS X. I followed this video as a guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxXMZV9f9P8 and followed all the instruction - I have all the necessary programmes installed.

The problem is in the PyCharm run configuration; apparently, I have to specify a path to a custom compiler (see attached picture) in the field *"Select custom compiler executable path (required on MAC OS X)".*

On Windows, it would be relatively easy by just selecting the installation folder in Program Files. On Mac however, I cannot seem to find the right path - if I go through applications to a MikTex compiler, it displays only some folders but nothing I can select (like an .exe file).

Without this specification, I cannot compile the files .tex files in PyCharm, which I would like to do in order to combine it with Python code.

Thank you all in advance!

[image: "Select custom compiler executable path (required on MAC OS X)"]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Why are you using MikTeX on a Mac in the first place? I'd just install MacTex (tug.org/mactex), it always sets up the same executable path for editors (etc to use): `/Library/TeX/texbin/` . I doubt MikTeX does this and have no idea here it places files on a Mac.

Comment: I installed PyCharm and the Texify plugin. I created a LaTeX file and run LaTeX on it with the “Run” menu. No issue at all: the program recognized that I have MacTeX installed. Do you?

Comment: Have you seen this [discussion on github](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/discussions/2414)? Also, thanks for giving TeXiFy a try! We don't have a Mac of our own, so if the [wiki](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki) is missing information about how to use TeXiFy on a Mac, feel free to [contribute to the wiki](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Contributing) or [start a discussion](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/discussions) (although in this case I think the above discussion should help you).

Comment: He has a later video here https://youtu.be/h-uZabWXCpc that says to use MacTex, like the above comments said.

Comment: It seems that on Mac, namely MacBook Air M1 with OS Ventura13.2, and PyCharm 2022.3.2, the compliation does not work with MacTex 2022 since the suggesetd TexLive compiler is missing completely. I resorted to TexShop that is ship together with MacTex, although I dont like that solution too much...

Comment: @Jorge.Squared Please try the latest version of TeXiFy, if it doesn't work please let us know https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/issues

Answer (score 1):

As suggested it is probably a better idea to install MacTeX. If you are using TeXiFy-IDEA version 0.7.7 or later, it should work out of the box.
If it does not, please let us know at https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/issues